# Find a Sylvester equation for $X^{-1}$

Tags: linear-algebra, inverse, numerical-linear-algebra, sylvester-equation

It's a problem from 18.065 ocw [assignment](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-065-matrix-methods-in-data-analysis-signal-processing-and-machine-learning-spring-2018/assignments/MIT18_065S18PSets.pdf#page=19), problem description is shown in the block below:

> If an invertible matrix $X$ satisfies the Sylvester equation $AX − XB = C$,
> find a Sylvester equation for $X^{−1}$.

Although I know that matrices $A$ and $B$ are normal, I still couldn't derive a formula for $X^{-1}$. Is there anybody having any tip about this problem?

---

Upadte: I misunderstood the problem at the first time, it is asking a Sylvester equation for inverse, not the inverse itself.

$$AX - XB = C$$
Multiplying both sides by $X^{-1}$ on the left and right:
$$X^{-1}(AX - XB)X^{-1} = X^{-1}CX^{-1}$$
$$X^{-1}A - BX^{-1} = X^{-1}CX^{-1}$$
Rearrange the position:
$$- BX^{-1} + X^{-1}A  = X^{-1}CX^{-1}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**: Multiply both sides of the equation $AX-XB = C$ by $X^{-1}$ on the left and $X^{-1}$ on the right. What do you get when you simplify things?

Comment: Thanks for reply, I realize that the problem is asking for Sylvester equation for inverse $X^{-1}$, not the inverse $X^{-1}$ itself.